# I can't change ios status bar color in my xamarin forms project

Tags: xamarin, mobile, xamarin.ios, statusbar

I am trying to change status bar letters color...I want white letters.
I am trying that using this line in 'AppDelegate':

```
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarStyle(statusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: false);
```

It's not working...Can someone help me?

Pleaseeeeeee

Comment: This is at least the third post you've made on this issue.  If you are trying a solution that was proposed in a previous question, you should respond there, not post yet another question.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to set the NavigationPage BarTextColor to white when the page is first created in app.xaml.cs

```
MainPage =  new NavigationPage(new Views.Splash2()) { BarTextColor = Color.White };
```